# Create User on Oracle 12c (pluggable)

Tags: sql, oracle, mining

I need to do Data Mining with Oracle on a Pluggable Oracle Database.
The users a created with a c# prefix.
If i want to install the Data Mining Repository via SQL Developer the Installation a User called "ODMRSYS" without the prefix and gives me a error. 
Any advice on solving this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: *Cause:    An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
           that was not valid for common users or roles.  In addition to
           the usual rules for user and role names, common user and role
           names must start with C## or c## and consist only of ASCII
           characters.

Comment: It's regarded to the create User query:                                                    create user ODMRSYS identified by Alxv19x default tablespace &&1 temporary tablespace &&2 quota UNLIMITED on &&1 PASSWORD EXPIRE

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to create the ODMRSYS user. ODMRSYS user is created internally by SQLDeveloper in the data mining repository installation step. In this user all the Data Minning "installation" repositories templates and binaries are deployed. That's why you cannot create a user named ODMRSYS.

However, you need a new user which is going to be the Data Miner user. This is the user you must use for data mining and where your mined data is going to be collected. You first create this user, connect to it, and then install the Data Mining repositories (SQL Developer will create and configure ODMRSYS user by itself)

AFAIK you don't need a common user for all your pluggable databases to deploy the data mining repositories.

Maybe this guide can help you: [Oracle Data Mining 17.2 OBE Series](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::::P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:11925,1)